# Help creating a dll for a custom control

Tags: c#, dll, controls

I'm going to ask a newbie question here.  I need to use a control I found online in my code, but it was written in the wrong language.  It is in C# and I am using VB.net for work.  I have all of the code for the control which works beautifully in C#, but I had issues with it not working very well in VB.

The source code and a demo project are available [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/treelistview.aspx), but I am not sure exactly which files I should use to build the dll for VB.

It seems a lot to ask, but would someone mind taking a look and pointing me in the right direction?

Cheers

Comment: Can you define "not working very well" ?  That means you do have a dll and linkedit to your VB project?

Comment: Apologies.  You can see the way the control is supposed to work in the screenshot on the linked site, but my control shows all of the entries in the treeview in a single column (no indentation), expanding nodes adds the nodes which are expanded to the end of the afformentioned column, and the other columns which are supposed to be separated underneat the column headers all show up in a single column with just a space between them.

Comment: I have included the dll, and I have access to the control and its members, properties, functions, and events through it.

Comment: The code there does not look terribly complex, might be worth a try converting it to VB using the online converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use/reference the DLL as-is from your visual basic solution. It doesn't matter whether it was written in C#, VB.NET or any other .net language.

Comment: Would the dll being an older version of .net effect this?

Comment: @Chapso: No I don't think so. So far I had no problems using old .NET libraries in my current projects (e.g. .net 1.1 libraries in .net 3.5 projects).

Answer (score 1):

Add the project to your solution, or just build it using your version of Visual Studio. Then add a reference, either to the project in the first case, or the .dll in the second.

If the Control doesn't work well, it's not because it's written in C# as opposed to VB.Net.

Answer (score 0):

One you compile a dll from the c# source it will work exactly the same as if it were written in vb.  You simply need to create a reference to the dll in visual studio.